# Bled Hot Water Heat but pressure increased again

Tags: hvac, heating, hot-water

I have a oil (converted to natural gas) hot water boiler running three zones of baseboard heat. Lately I have been hearing water rushing through one of my zones (I don't hear it on the other zones). Additionally the boiler pressure is 20 psi. From research it should be about 12psi. I opened the spigot on the affected zone and drained about 4 gallons of water until it flowed freely without spitting. The pressure went down to 10-12psi. However as soon as I shut the spigot, the pressure climbed again back to 20psi. I can still hear washing rushing through the pipes but could that be just refilling?

What should my next step be? Should I drain more water on the zone or is there another valve that needs opening? Here are pictures of my system. You can see the hose on the spigot I opened.

UPDATE: Following the comments below, I reduced the pressure on the fill valve which reduced the boiler to 15 psi. I will wait to see if I hear the water rushing through the pipes.

UPDATE: Water still rushing through pipes.

[image: bleed spigot on affected zone]

[image: whole system]

[image: right side of system]

Comment: Back off the pressure on the fill valve.  Upper right above the pressure tank, right after the Watts 9-D.  It may need to be replaced.

Comment: @PaulLogan I know what you mean by the watts 9D?

Comment: @PaulLogan I found the fill valve but I don't know how to reduce the pressure.

Comment: It is a watts T1156F valve.

Comment: You also need to bleed from the highest billed valve in the zone.  If this zone is upstairs it will be on that floor.

Comment: @Tyson it is a ranch. None of the baseboards have valves upstairs.

Comment: Post updated with pressure adjustment.

Comment: Water is still rushing through pipes.

Comment: If it was spitting when you drained it, then it sounds like it is getting air in the system. Possibly not bleeding air like it should. The bleeder on top of the large blue tee above the pressure tank is supposed to slowly bleed off accumulated air. It may be clogged.

Comment: archon is right on the money, replace the auto vent on top of the scoop. And make sure that cap stays loose.  Sometime it get closed tight when it dribbles. Some small amount of dribbling is OK.

Comment: @ArchonOSX I know what you are talking about? How do I replace it? Can I just unscrew it off and replace or do I have to do anything with the water/boiler first?

Comment: Yes it just unscrews. But you might check the cap as Paul Logan suggested. It should be loose. This allows air that has been separated to escape. Someone that didn't know this may have tightened it, preventing the air from escaping. To replace it, you would need to make sure the system pressure is 0 since it doesn't look like there are any isolation valves.

Comment: @ArchonOSX the cap is actually barely on there. That was one of the first things I checked based on my research. Thanks for the help.